# python (pycharm) cant find idlelib

Tags: python

I installed a new virtual environment for python3.11 for pycharm for my application which is using idlelib: in idlelib there is the Hovertooltip which i need for the GUI.

```
  from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip
```

Apparently because of the new environment, the python interpreter does not find "idlelib" but i also cant install it, neither with python nor with pip

I use python3.11 but it seems as if idlelib (and the Hovertip) is not acessable anymore?

Comment: `idlelib` is built-in standard module. Debug your installation. First, remove pycharm from the equation and try from your terminal.

Comment: Hovertip is not build-in or an module in build-in tooltip. I have the same result when i start the code without pycharm.

Comment: It definitely is built-in: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py. You need to repair your installation somehow, probably by reinstalling python. What OS do you use and how did you install Python?

Comment: I user Ubuntu 22.04 and installed python via apt-get.